# How do you get dependencies?

Tags: clojure, dependencies, monads

I've never used clojure before and I'm trying to get the 'domonad' function/macro so I can play with it and learn from [this tutorial](http://vimeo.com/20798376) on monads which is quite good. I heard it was in clojure-contrib, then moved to clojure.algo

I tried

```
user=> (ns your-namespace
  (:require clojure.contrib.monads))
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/contrib/monads__init.class or clojure/contrib/monads.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
user=> (ns your-namespace
  (:require clojure.algo.monads))
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/algo/monads__init.class or clojure/contrib/monads.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

Nothing works. I think I don't know how to use libraries.

How can I get this dependency?

Comment: You need to find and download each dependency (and it's dependencies) and add them to the classpath at runtime; or use a dependency management / build tool like [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/). Leiningen is much easier, and it's how most of us do it.

Comment: Best not to direct people learning Clojure anywhere but Leiningen. Use Leiningen to add the dependencies.

Comment: ALso check out lein-try. HTH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **Use [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) for project management** in clojure.

- install leinengen
- run "lein new project-name"
- cd project-name and edit project.clj to add the dependency
  `[org.clojure/algo.monads "0.1.5"]`
- run lein repl, or better yes use Emacs and the cider-mode package